# Armadillo 'cor' function returning scalar

Tags: c++, statistics, armadillo

I'm trying to calculate the autocorrelation of a vector of doubles using Armadillo, as following:

```
QVector<double> calculateAutocorrelation(QVector<double> samples){
  arma::Row<double> armadillo_samples(samples.toStdVector());//Convert samples to armadillo vector
  arma::Row<double> armadillo_autocorrelation = cor(armadillo_samples); //compute the autocorrelation, returns a 1x1 matrix!
  QVector<double> ret(samples.size());
  for(int i = 0; i <samples.size();i++)
      ret[i] = armadillo_autocorrelation(i);//copy back into a QVector
  return ret;
}
```

However, as commented on the 2nd line, cor(armadillo_samples) returns a 1x1 matrix instead of another vector, as I would expect.
 I have downloaded the latests stable release of Armadillo from their website (5.100.1) and tried this code on Linux with MKL enabled and on Windows with the precompiled BLAS/LAPACK libraries enabled.
Am I misunderstanding how this function works/using it wrong?

Relevant Links:
-[Armadillo documentation of cor](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#cor)
-Autocorrelation on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation#Estimation) (there's a link to Mathworld in the Armadillo documation which is usefull too, but I can't link to it)

Comment: Where the Armadillo documentation mentions cor(X) is the autocorrelation, they presumably mean the zero-lag autocorrelation only (not all lags). (The documentation doesn't mention the return type of the various functions; that seems unusual for programming documentation, but oh well.) I don't see an all-lags autocorrelation function listed. Do you have to use Armadillo? Probably you could find another library, or write it yourself -- the autocorrelation function is easily expressed in terms of the discrete Fourier transform.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a 1x1 matrix to a pure scalar in Armadillo, use the [as_scalar()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#as_scalar) function. For example:

```
mat X(1,1, fill::ones);

double val = as_scalar(X);
```